# How to setup Elasticsearch server on remote Ubuntu server?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have purchased space of 1Gb Ubuntu server to deploy my Elasticsearch Application.
I followed the guide below to deploy Elasticsearch server.
[Link to guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-ubuntu-16-04)
Now whenever I try to access Elasticsearch server using a curl command, it shows the following error

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 9200: Connection refused

Here is the curl command I tried

```
curl -XGET '0.0.0.0:9200/?pretty'
```

Which step could I have missed or is not shown in the guide?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your elasticsearch service running?

Check with the following command

```
systemctl status elasticsearch
```

If it is not running try to start it with

```
systemctl start elasticsearch
```

After a few minutes check if it is still running or crashed using `systemctl status elasticsearch`. If it has crashed please add more details to your question.

Comment: I checked the status of it, as it showing **status=1/failure** so I tried to start it with cmd given but it showing error  
  
  
> Failed to start elasticsearch.service: Access denied